# How to keep sshd alive on MAC OSX?

Tags: macos, ssh, connection

How do I keep sshd alive so I can connect at any point?

I'm not trying to keep an existing SSH connection alive - I can't create it in the first place.

Environment:

- Mac running OSX 10.9.3.
- Attempting to ssh to it from another machine when it has been idle for a while fails (times out).  Waking up the display (press escape) makes SSH connection start working again.
- The Mac is connected to the AC power, and indicates as such.
- The Mac is set to sleep "Never", with the display at "1 min".  The hard disk is set to never sleep. (different settings for battery, but as mentioned it's not on battery)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to setup sshd: GUI and (the real way) command line.  Assuming 10.6 or later...

**GUI**:

- System Preferences > Sharing > Check "Remote Login"
- Make sure you set "Allow Access for" to whomever you want to restrict this to

**Command Line**

- `/usr/bin/systemsetup -setremotelogin on`
- Modify `/etc/sshd_config` to the settings optimal for your environment.  There are lots of articles on this so I'll spare the electrons...